# Java serialization to an array

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialize a matrix of buttons (`new JButton [6][6]`;) so that I can save values to a file and later reload them to the matrix. I found code online that saves the data successfully, but I am having trouble loading the data and returning its value to the matrix.

I tried using the following code:

```
public class SaveListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ab) {
        saveArray("customlevel", buttons);
    }

    public void saveArray(String filename, JButton[][] write) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(gzos);
            out.writeObject(write);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public class LoadListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        loadArray("customlevel", buttons);
    }
}

public JButton[][] loadArray(String filename, JButton[][] read) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(gzis);
        // in.readObject(read);
        JButton[][] load = (JButton[][]) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        return load;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: And what's the *specific* problem ? Exception etc.?

Comment: Problem is in loading value back to Buttons array, it doesn't work although code seems to be alright and doesn't have any exception problems.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  we going to play 20 questions?

Comment: It doesn't load saved value back into Buttons array

Comment: instead of `System.out.println(e);` write `e.printStacktrace();` and check your logs again.

Comment: @ArslanBerbic The code you posted is really messy - can you please format it a bit and fix the indentation? I tried to format it through Eclipse, but at least the braces do not match at all

Comment: show the code where you call `loadArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusion is coming from the fact that you are returning loaded array from your loadArray() method, but ignoring the result of the function call in your ActionListener.performAction function. If you want buttons to have the return value, just assign it, so do

`buttons = loadArray(fileName)`

Answer (score 2):

In `loadArray()` you are both passing in an array and returning an array.  the passed in array is ignored.  are you somehow expecting that the passed in array will be populated?